# Context aware typeclasses

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, tagless-final

I'm working on some application which works with files on a hard disk. I have the following "entity":

```
final case class File(path: String)
final case class FileChecksum(f: File, checksum: Long)
```

I also have the following typeclass:

```
trait Checksum[T]{
    def checksum(t: T): Long
}
```

All these is operated by the following trait:

```
trait Model{
    def fromFile(file: File)(implicit checksum: Checksum[File]): FileChecksum
}
```

And and it looks fine. But I decided to refactor it and apply tagless final. So the model now looks like:

```
trait Model[F[_]]{
    def fromFile(file: File)(implicit checksum: Checksum[F, File]): F[FileChecksum]
}

trait Checksum[F[_], T]{
    def checksum(t: T): F[Long]
}
```

The problem that confused me is the the typeclass `trait Checksum[F[_], T]`. It now depends on the context `F`. Is that really a typeclass? Or I'm looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Checksum[F[_], T] is still a typeclass, but one now parameterized by a higher-kinded type (HKT), that takes a one-argument type constructor.

Thus, F takes as a parameter type constructors such as List or Option. That is:

```
def checksum(t: T): F[Long]
```

with its return type F[Long], could be implemented to return List[Long] or Option[Long].

I hope this helps. See also: https://typelevel.org/blog/2016/08/21/hkts-moving-forward.html  and https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/scala-types-of-a-higher-kind

Comment: Or, importantly, `Identity[Long]` (i.e. `Long`, given `type Identity[A] = A`).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov The thing I'm not sure about is the mathematical definition of typeclass (if there is so). Can we give it a formall definition using Category language?

Comment: But the problem with such a trait is that I cannot simply provide its implementation for some type (say, `File`). I need to be aware of the context (in my case it will be `IO`).